# Google Dataflow failed to create a template to GCS

Tags: python, dataflow, google-cloud-storage

I am building a beam pipeline on Google Cloud dataflow.

I am getting an error that cloud dataflow does not have permissions to write to the template directory. (no storage.objects.create access)

[This is the error i'm getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUdor.png)

I have given the service account Storage Admin and Viewer permission.
API is enabled.

I have removed the Storage Admin role from the service account and then add it again.

This is the pipeline file

```html
from __future__ import annotations

import json
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
import os

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import _BeamArgumentParser

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = <apikey.json>

class ArgumentParser(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser: _BeamArgumentParser) -> None:
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--input_file',
            help='Path to the file to ingest data from',
            default='gs://dataflow_marketing_datamart/json_to_bq_test/input_data.jsonl',
            type=str
        )
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--bq_table',
            help='Output BigQuery table in the form of <PROJECT>:<DATASET>.<TABLE>',
            default='marketing-datamart:dataflow_testing.custom_template_test',
            type=str
        )
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--bq_schema',
            help='JSON string of the BigQuery table',
            default="""
            {
                "fields": [
                    {
                    "description": "Name of the fruit",
                    "name": "fruit",
                    "type": "STRING",
                    "mode": "REQUIRED"
                    },
                    {
                    "description": "Quantity of the fruit",
                    "name": "quantity",
                    "type": "INTEGER",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    },
                    {
                    "description": "Color of the fruit",
                    "name": "color",
                    "type": "STRING",
                    "mode": "NULLABLE"
                    }
                ]
            }""",
            type=str
        )



class FormatInputText(beam.DoFn):
    """beam.io.WriteToBigQuery expects a list of one dictionary, but the raw output from 
    beam.io.ReadFromText is string. This converts the string to the required format"""
    def process(self, line):
        return [json.loads(line)]


def main(argv=None, save_main_session=True):
    """Main entry point"""

    pipeline_args = []
    pipeline_args.extend([
        '--runner=DataflowRunner',
        '--project=$PROJECTt',
        '--region=asia-southeast1',
        '--staging_location=$BUCKET/staging',
        '--temp_location=$BUCKET/temp',
        '--job_name=custom-job-test',
        '--template_location=$BUCKET/template/trial3_template'
    ])

    # We use the save_main_session option because one or more DoFn's in this
    # workflow rely on global context (e.g., a module imported at module level).
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session

    template_options = pipeline_options.view_as(ArgumentParser)
    template_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session

    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        
        input_lines = (p 
                    | "Read input schema" >> beam.io.ReadFromText(template_options.input_file)
                    | "Format lines" >> beam.ParDo(FormatInputText()))

        bq_write = input_lines | "Write to BigQuery" >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            table=lambda x: f"{template_options.bq_table.get()}",
            schema=lambda x: json.loads(template_options.bq_schema.get()),
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

I recently used Dataflow and had some similar confusion surrounding the usage of service accounts. The problem for me was that I didn't realise that the dataflow job starts on a separate "worker service account", not the service account that created the job.

You will notice the service account name is `-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`, this is the default worker service account, and likely not the service account that created the dataflow job.

I would suggest reading [this part](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#worker_service_account) of the Dataflow permissions documentation.

You have the option of either creating a user-managed service account to use for the operation (this is configurable when creating the job), or you must make sure you are assigning the IAM permissions to the default worker service account.